# Where should a ruby constant live?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, constants

```
 %div{:id=>[Arsenal[@home.page_color]], :class=> "page"}
```

I'm using the following constant Arsenal in my Home#Page view. Where should this constant live in order to be used by the view in ruby on rails?

Right now I'm met with a `ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Arsenal):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it in a own initializer file:

```
#config/initializers/setup_constants.rb
Arsenal = ["ccc", "ddd",...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its more like a model. I would rather put it like the following:

```
/app/models
class Arsenal

  @@data = {'ccc' => 'CCC', 'ddd' => 'DDD',...];

  def []index
    @@data[index]
  end
end
```